# how to align <h2> element and <span>hamburger menu</span> side by side?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a 'hamburger menu' that also has the word 'menu', with both the word menu and the hamburger clickable. I have achieved the desired functionality; however, I cannot get my  element with the word 'menu' to be horizontally aligned with the hamburger lines. Every solution I have come up with so far disrupts the functionality of the nav bar. If someone can please help me get the two components side by side while still maintaining functionality, it would be much appreciated.

```css
#menu__toggle {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span::before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  #menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span::after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  #menu__toggle:checked ~ .menu__box {
    left: 0 !important;
  }
  .menu__btn {
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .menu__btn > span,
  .menu__btn > span::before,
  .menu__btn > span::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #616161;
    transition-duration: .25s;
  }
  .menu__btn > span::before {
    content: '';
    top: -8px;
  }
  .menu__btn > span::after {
    content: '';
    top: 8px;
  }
  .menu__box {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 80px 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ECEFF1;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    transition-duration: .25s;
  }
  .menu__item {
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: .25s;
  }
  .menu__item:hover {
    background-color: #CFD8DC;
```

```html
     <div class="hamburger-menu">
        <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
            <h2 id="menu">MENU</h2>
            <span></span>
        </label>
    
        <ul class="menu__box">
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Team</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
  #menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn .menu__hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn .menu__hamburger::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn .menu__hamburger::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.menu__btn {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  
  /* what i added */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
}

.menu__btn .menu__hamburger,
.menu__btn .menu__hamburger::before,
.menu__btn .menu__hamburger::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #616161;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__btn .menu__hamburger::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn .menu__hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
  <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
            <h2 id="menu">MENU</h2>
            <div><span class="menu__hamburger"></span></div>
        </label>

  <ul class="menu__box">
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Team</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I wrapped your hamburger in a div, replaced all your previous `.menu__btn > span` selectors with `.menu__btn .menu__hamburger`.

To align the text with your icon I used `display: flex` and `align-items: center`.

If you want to learn more about flexbox you can check the MDN docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox